# C When executing C file in terminal, how can I add line break to input when prompted by fgets() or scanf()?

Tags: c, terminal, scanf, fgets

**Scenario 1**

```
char string[MAX_BYTES] = "This is a string\nthat I'm using\nfor scenario 1";
```

**Scenario 2**

```
printf("Enter string: ");
fgets(string, MAX_BYTES, stdin);
```

If I provide the string in-code (scen. 1), I can line break with '`\n'`.

But if prompting in terminal with `fgets()` or `scanf()` (scen. 2), pressing `enter` continues the execution of code.

How can I add a line break to input without triggering the rest of the code?

Comment: You could call `fgets()` in a loop, concatenating the input to the result string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually that can't be done with `fgets` and `scanf`, but you can use `getchar` instead:

```
int ch;
int idx = 0;
while( ( (ch = getchar()) != EOF ) && idx < MAX_BYTES)
{
    string[idx++] = ch;
}
printf("%s", string);
```

Note `getchar` will accept any input including `\n` and the `while` loop terminates when `EOF` ie <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> from `stdin`. You then copy each character to the buffer accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. So in general should a `getchar()` loop be used when accepting terminal input?  What scenarios then are `fgets()` and/or `scanf()` better used for?

Comment: `scanf` is for formatted input (int, double, etc.), `fgets` is for line input, `getchar` is for simple character input. Usually `scanf`, `fgets` are superior, but `getchar` has its own use cases

Comment: So in general, if I want to take line input, I'm using `fgets()`. I'd only use `scanf()` is there are any formatted input (numbers, decimal numbers etc) correct?

Comment: You should only use `scanf` if you are in a university course learning how to use `scanf`.  It has no place in production code.

Comment: Is `getline()` relatively new? The Keringhan+Ritchie C book has an example that creates a function called getline(). The book includes the `stdio.h` library, which is where `getline()` is. I can only create my own `getline()` function if i remove the `stdio.h` library. I'm assuming the example is out-dated?